# Power steering squeeling

Tags: chevrolet, noise, power-steering, truck, belt

I have a 65 Chevy truck with 350 engine. New power steering pump and new belt but it squeals really loud for 1 to 2 minutes every time I start it. Pump fluid is at cold temp level. When I put pump on I turned steering wheel one side to the other to bleed air out. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Is the belt tight enough? What is the deflection on its longest run?

Answer (score 1):

What is your belt tension?  Does the squeal happen after the system warms up, and you make turns requiring power assist?

I am inclined upon the information you provided to say that you have a belt undertension problem.  How clean is the belt?

And answer @Paulster2's question on the belt deflection.  You might push with 10 to 15# pressure when you check the deflection.  If the long run is 12" your deflection should be under 1/2".

Is your belt manually tensioned, or is there a spring loaded belt tensioner?

One last thing...check your belt routing to assure that you have the belt properly sequenced over the pulleys.